# C# HTML5 Websocket Server

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying to create a C# Websocket server but I just don't seem to get it working.
I now have a server that accepts the TCPClient, receives the HTTP request from the client and that tries to send back a HTTP response so the HTML5 WebSocket handshake can be completed.

I believe there is something wrong with my handshake that the server sends to the client.
I read the draft ([Websocket 76 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76#section-1.3)) which states that at the end of the handshake a response has to be given for the two keys that are given. This response gets calculated by the server.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 8181;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback;

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] receivedBytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;

        // Enter the listening loop.
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!\n");

            data = null;

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;
            

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while ((i = stream.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, i);

                Console.WriteLine("Received:");
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                Byte[] response_token = hashResponse(data);


                string handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\n"
                    + "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                    + "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost\r\n"
                    + "Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/websession\r\n"
                    + "\r\n";

                Byte[] writtenBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(handshake);

                stream.Write(writtenBytes, 0, writtenBytes.Length);
                stream.Write(response_token, 0, response_token.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Send:");
                Console.WriteLine(handshake);

                string strHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response_token);
                Console.WriteLine(strHash);
            }                
        }
    }

    static Byte[] hashResponse(string receivedData)
    {
        string strDel = "\r\n";
        char[] delimeter = strDel.ToCharArray();

        string Key1 = null;
        string Key2 = null;
        string hash = null;
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

        string[] lines = receivedData.Split(delimeter);
        Key1 = lines[10].Substring(20);
        Key2 = lines[12].Substring(20);
        hash = lines[16];

        Int64 numbersKey1 = Convert.ToInt64(string.Join(null, Regex.Split(Key1, "[^\\d]")));
        Int64 numbersKey2 = Convert.ToInt64(string.Join(null, Regex.Split(Key2, "[^\\d]")));

        Int64 numberSpaces1 = countSpaces(Key1);
        Int64 numberSpaces2 = countSpaces(Key2);

        int dividedKey1 = (int) (numbersKey1 / numberSpaces1);
        int dividedKey2 = (int) (numbersKey2 / numberSpaces2);

        Byte[] encodedKey1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dividedKey1.ToString());
        Byte[] encodedKey2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dividedKey2.ToString());
        Byte[] encodedHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash);

        Byte[] combined = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dividedKey1.ToString() + dividedKey2.ToString() + hash);

        Byte[] responseHash = md5.ComputeHash(combined); 
        return responseHash;
    }

    static int countSpaces(string key)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        char[] charArray = key.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in charArray)
        {
            if (c.Equals(' '))
                counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

The HTML page (which is named Test.html) I'm using for testing is hosted by an apache webserver which runs on my computer I access it by browsing (in Chrome) to http://localhost/Test.html

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong because I'm getting quite desperate.

Thanks in advance

Dennis

Answer (score 13):

Here's a sample server I wrote illustrating the handshake phase in accordance to the  [draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8080);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string line = string.Empty;
                while ((line = ReadLine(stream)) != string.Empty)
                {
                    var tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && tokens.Length > 1)
                    {
                        headers[tokens[0]] = tokens[1].Trim();
                    }
                }

                var key = new byte[8];
                stream.Read(key, 0, key.Length);

                var key1 = headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key1"];
                var key2 = headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key2"];

                var numbersKey1 = Convert.ToInt64(string.Join(null, Regex.Split(key1, "[^\\d]")));
                var numbersKey2 = Convert.ToInt64(string.Join(null, Regex.Split(key2, "[^\\d]")));
                var numberSpaces1 = CountSpaces(key1);
                var numberSpaces2 = CountSpaces(key2);

                var part1 = (int)(numbersKey1 / numberSpaces1);
                var part2 = (int)(numbersKey2 / numberSpaces2);

                var result = new List<byte>();
                result.AddRange(GetBigEndianBytes(part1));
                result.AddRange(GetBigEndianBytes(part2));
                result.AddRange(key);

                var response =
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Upgrade: WebSocket" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Connection: Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " + headers["Origin"] + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8080/websession" + Environment.NewLine + 
                    Environment.NewLine;

                var bufferedResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                stream.Write(bufferedResponse, 0, bufferedResponse.Length);
                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    var handshake = md5.ComputeHash(result.ToArray());
                    stream.Write(handshake, 0, handshake.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int CountSpaces(string key)
    {
        return key.Length - key.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length;
    }

    static string ReadLine(Stream stream)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var buffer = new List<byte>();
        while (true)
        {
            buffer.Add((byte)stream.ReadByte());
            var line = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
            if (line.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                return line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
            }
        }
    }

    static byte[] GetBigEndianBytes(int value)
    {
        var bytes = 4;
        var buffer = new byte[bytes];
        int num = bytes - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            buffer[num - i] = (byte)(value & 0xffL);
            value = value >> 8;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

And a sample client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/websession');
        socket.onopen = function() {
            alert('handshake successfully established. May send data now...');
        };
        socket.onclose = function() {
            alert('connection closed');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, first of all +1 for a working sample, I love that. However, I've tried your sample using Chrome 16, and it was not working because Chrome it's not sending Sec-WebSockets-Key1 header as your server expects, which UA did you use for this test?

Comment: @EugenioMiró, I used Chrome, no idea which version it was by the time I posted this answer: May 3, 2011. My answer was based on `draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00`. There is now the [RFC 6455](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) which I believe is the latest specification but I have no idea which one does Chrome 16 implement.

Comment: Hi Darin, I found Chrome now it's sending 13 as version on the headers so I followed from there, thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 6):

Here is very simple Websocket echo server which I implemented using plain Sockets.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SimpleWebsocketServer {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var listeningSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listeningSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port: 80));
            listeningSocket.Listen(0);

            while (true) {
                var clientSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();

                Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

                var receivedData = new byte[1000000];
                var receivedDataLength = clientSocket.Receive(receivedData);

                var requestString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData, 0, receivedDataLength);

                if (new Regex("^GET").IsMatch(requestString)) {
                    const string eol = "\r\n";

                    var receivedWebSocketKey = new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(requestString).Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                    var keyHash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(receivedWebSocketKey + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"));

                    var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + eol;
                    response += "Connection: Upgrade" + eol;
                    response += "Upgrade: websocket" + eol;
                    response += "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(keyHash) + eol;
                    response += eol;

                    var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                    clientSocket.Send(responseBytes);
                }

                while (true) {
                    receivedData = new byte[1000000];
                    clientSocket.Receive(receivedData);

                    if ((receivedData[0] & (byte)Opcode.CloseConnection) == (byte)Opcode.CloseConnection) {
                        // Close connection request.
                        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
                        clientSocket.Close();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        var receivedPayload = ParsePayloadFromFrame(receivedData);
                        var receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedPayload);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Client: {receivedString}");

                        var response = $"ECHO: {receivedString}";
                        var dataToSend = CreateFrameFromString(response);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Server: {response}");

                        clientSocket.Send(dataToSend);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ParsePayloadFromFrame(byte[] incomingFrameBytes) {
            var payloadLength = 0L;
            var totalLength = 0L;
            var keyStartIndex = 0L;

            // 125 or less.
            // When it's below 126, second byte is the payload length.
            if ((incomingFrameBytes[1] & 0x7F) < 126) {
                payloadLength = incomingFrameBytes[1] & 0x7F;
                keyStartIndex = 2;
                totalLength = payloadLength + 6;
            }

            // 126-65535.
            // When it's 126, the payload length is in the following two bytes
            if ((incomingFrameBytes[1] & 0x7F) == 126) {
                payloadLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(new[] { incomingFrameBytes[3], incomingFrameBytes[2] }, 0);
                keyStartIndex = 4;
                totalLength = payloadLength + 8;
            }

            // 65536 +
            // When it's 127, the payload length is in the following 8 bytes.
            if ((incomingFrameBytes[1] & 0x7F) == 127) {
                payloadLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(new[] { incomingFrameBytes[9], incomingFrameBytes[8], incomingFrameBytes[7], incomingFrameBytes[6], incomingFrameBytes[5], incomingFrameBytes[4], incomingFrameBytes[3], incomingFrameBytes[2] }, 0);
                keyStartIndex = 10;
                totalLength = payloadLength + 14;
            }

            if (totalLength > incomingFrameBytes.Length) {
                throw new Exception("The buffer length is smaller than the data length.");
            }

            var payloadStartIndex = keyStartIndex + 4;

            byte[] key = { incomingFrameBytes[keyStartIndex], incomingFrameBytes[keyStartIndex + 1], incomingFrameBytes[keyStartIndex + 2], incomingFrameBytes[keyStartIndex + 3] };

            var payload = new byte[payloadLength];
            Array.Copy(incomingFrameBytes, payloadStartIndex, payload, 0, payloadLength);
            for (int i = 0; i < payload.Length; i++) {
                payload[i] = (byte)(payload[i] ^ key[i % 4]);
            }

            return payload;
        }

        public enum Opcode {
            Fragment = 0,
            Text = 1,
            Binary = 2,
            CloseConnection = 8,
            Ping = 9,
            Pong = 10
        }

        public static byte[] CreateFrameFromString(string message, Opcode opcode = Opcode.Text) {
            var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            byte[] frame;

            if (payload.Length < 126) {
                frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
                frame[1] = (byte)payload.Length;
                Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 2, payload.Length);
            } else if (payload.Length >= 126 && payload.Length <= 65535) {
                frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length option*/ + 2 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
                frame[1] = 126;
                frame[2] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 8) & 255);
                frame[3] = (byte)(payload.Length & 255);
                Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 4, payload.Length);
            } else {
                frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length option*/ + 8 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
                frame[1] = 127; // <-- Indicates that payload length is in following 8 bytes.
                frame[2] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 56) & 255);
                frame[3] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 48) & 255);
                frame[4] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 40) & 255);
                frame[5] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 32) & 255);
                frame[6] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 24) & 255);
                frame[7] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 16) & 255);
                frame[8] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 8) & 255);
                frame[9] = (byte)(payload.Length & 255);
                Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 10, payload.Length);
            }

            frame[0] = (byte)((byte)opcode | 0x80 /*FIN bit*/);

            return frame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent several hours looking for a simple command line websocket example for dotnet without any library bloat or something less basic than receive, send and shut down, this is the most down to the point one.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the handshake data before trying to receive data on the socket

Here is an example that might help you

[websocksample](http://ashishware.com/websocksample.shtml)

Comment: I'm not really trying to receive data before the handshake, It's the request the client sends to the server which I write on the console screen.

Comment: One you get a connection you are trying to receive data prior to sending the handshake response "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol etc" I think you need to send this the moment you receive a connection. Before you receive data on the stream that is.

Answer (score 1):

Do't know if you can compile Objective C, but [this project is really pretty cool](https://github.com/mattpat/Blackbox)...

> Blackbox is an embeddable Cocoa HTTP server -- that allows you to associate HTTP
>   resources with Cocoa "responder" objects (kind of like Twisted Web
>   does for Python) rather than files on your filesystem.
>
> With Blackbox, you can create personal file sharers in a snap, write
>   applications that communicate with each other over HTTP, and easily
>   create web control interfaces for headless applications.

It basically is a [Comet server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) in a nice package. I wish I could say more about it, but I'm still kind of trying to figure out sockets myself...

[image: Please note the "Comet demo" window is a concoction of mine, so don't get frustrated when you run the demo, just open your browser!]