# WebSocket Draft 76 handshake confusion

Tags: c#, html, websocket

I think I am prolbably the millionth person to have issues here; I hope that someone can help me out for sure!

Anyways; I have this C# server, which I am trying to get functioning well with WebSockets, sadly I am unable to get the damn thing to establish a connection! Tearing my hair out isn't helping either.

```
    internal class Request
    {
        private delegate void _create_request(Request request);

        private Request(_create_request create_function)
        {
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Headers["Upgrade"] = null;
            Headers["Connection"] = null;
            Headers["Host"] = null;
            Headers["Origin"] = null;
            Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key1"] = null;
            Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key2"] = null;
            Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"] = null;
            Success = false;
            Secure = false;
            Method = "GET";
            Code = new byte[8];

            create_function(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// the code value is the last 8 bytes of the packet
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] Code { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// the resource is the directory being associated with optional extension
        /// eg: ws://localhost:90/[resource]
        /// </summary>
        public string Resource { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// the resource is the directory being associated with optional extensions
        /// </summary>
        public bool Success { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// this value can either be "GET"
        /// </summary>
        public string Method { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// is this connection using a wss:// or ws:// configuration
        /// </summary>
        public bool Secure { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// these values contain information about our connection
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// this value will give you the responce buffer to pass to the WebSocket server
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] Response
        {
            get
            {
                if (!Success)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                byte[] key_value1 = _get_key_value(Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key1"]);
                byte[] key_value2 = _get_key_value(Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key2"]);
                byte[] concatenatedKeys = new byte[16];

                Array.Copy(key_value1, 0, concatenatedKeys, 0, 4);
                Array.Copy(key_value2, 0, concatenatedKeys, 4, 4);
                Array.Copy(Code, 0, concatenatedKeys, 8, 8);

                // MD5 Hash
                System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 MD5Service = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
                byte[] challenge_buffer = MD5Service.ComputeHash(concatenatedKeys);

                string response = "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\n";
                response += "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n";
                response += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
                response += "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " + Headers["Origin"] + "\r\n";

                string location = ((Secure) ? "wss://" : "ws://") + Headers["Host"] + "/" + Resource;
                response += "Sec-WebSocket-Location: " + location + "\r\n";

                string protocol = Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"];
                if (Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"] == null)
                {
                    protocol = "*";
                }
                response += "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: " + protocol.Trim(' ') + "\r\n";
                response += "\r\n";

                byte[] response_buffer = new byte[response.Length + 16];
                Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response), 0, response_buffer, 0, response.Length);
                Array.Copy(challenge_buffer, 0, response_buffer, response.Length, 16);

                return response_buffer;
            }
        }

        internal byte[] _get_key_value(string key)
        {
            byte[] value = new byte[4];
            ulong r = 0;
            ulong s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (key[i] > '0' && key[i] < '9')
                {
                    r = r * 10 + key[i] - '0';
                }
                else if (key[i] == ' ')
                {
                    s++;
                }
            }
            value = BitConverter.GetBytes(r / s);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(value);
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this function will instantiate a new request object, from request data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">the request data</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal static Request Instantiate(byte[] data)
        {
            string sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            return new Request(delegate(Request request)
            {
                string _regex_descriptor = @"^([^ ]+)\s\/([^ ]+)\sHTTP/1.1";
                string _regex_header = @"\n([^:]+):\s([^\r\n]+)";

                string _regex_secure = "^ws([^:]+)?:\\/\\/";
                Match match_descriptor = Regex.Match(sdata, _regex_descriptor);
                MatchCollection match_headers = Regex.Matches(sdata, _regex_header);

                if (match_descriptor.Success)
                {
                    request.Method = match_descriptor.Groups[1].Value;
                    request.Resource = match_descriptor.Groups[2].Value;
                    //Console.WriteLine("Method = " + request.Method);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Resource = " + request.Resource);
                }
                else return;
                if (match_headers.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Match match in match_headers)
                    {
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            if (match.Groups[1].Value == "Host")
                            {
                                Match match_secure = Regex.Match(match.Groups[2].Value, _regex_secure);
                                if (match_secure.Success)
                                {
                                    request.Secure = (match_secure.Groups[1].Value == "s");
                                }
                            }
                            request.Headers[match.Groups[1].Value] = match.Groups[2].Value;
                            //Console.WriteLine("Header[\"" + match.Groups[1].Value + "\"] = " + match.Groups[2].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else return;

                Array.Copy(data, data.Length - 8, request.Code, 0, 8);

                request.Success = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

Basically, if you call `myRequest = Request.Instantiate(byte[] handshake_packet);`
then call `myRequest.Response` to generate a response buffer; if anyone sees anything wrong with my method here, let me know; because I really can not settle for sleep until I fix this.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835944/c-html5-websocket-server/5866975#5866975

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov **THANK YOU MOTHA F!@#ER** <3

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not include `0` or `9` as a number. Secondly, `_get_key_value` returns `byte[8]` and not `byte[4]`.

So, first change the following inside `_get_key_value` (note `>=` and `<=`):

```
if (key[i] >= '0' && key[i] <= '9')
```

And change the following inside that same function (note the cast to `int` because it will always be a whole number, and an integer has 4 bytes which is correct):

```
value = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)(r / s));
```

Because [the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) states:

> ... the |Sec-    WebSocket-Key1| field, expressed as a big-endian **32 bit number**, the    number obtained from processing the |Sec-WebSocket-Key2| field, again expressed as a big-endian **32 bit number**, ...

Now I'm able to get the correct response from the example request from the [article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).

Comment: what was that you are implying about the Big-Endian format, that I am not properly converting it to big-endian?

Comment: It is still not working with these changes, although my results are as you said, correct, at least compared to the wiki-pedia result.. however, I am still unable to establish a connection.

before sending the response, do I need to add an \r\n or an \n at the end? I remember before when working with sockets, I always needed the ending \n or \0

Comment: @Kyle Gibbar: You were using big-endian, but the division resulted not in an integer (4 bytes), but in 8 bytes. You were copying the first 4 bytes which were all zero. By casting to an integer this problem was solved. I'm not aware of any ending, just `\r\n` between headers and `\r\n\r\n` between headers and body.

Comment: @Kyle Gibbar: Also, what browser are you using? If Chrome, you might want to consult chrome://net-internals/ to see the actual received response (which might not be what you sent, in which case the transmission failed somehow).