# Creating a "Hello World" WebSocket example

Tags: c#, javascript, websocket

I don't understand why I cannot make the following code work. I want to connect with JavaScript to my server console application. And then send data to the server.

Here is the server code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9998);
        server.Start();
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024]; 
            // wait for data to be received
            var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                
            var r = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            // write received data to the console
            Console.WriteLine(r.Substring(0, bytesRead));
        }
    }
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9998/service");
        ws.onopen = function () {
            ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            var received_msg = evt.data;
            alert("Message is received...");
        };
        ws.onclose = function () {
            // websocket is closed.
            alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
```

When I run that code this is what happens:

[image]

Note that when I run the JavaScript the server accepts and successfully establishes a connection. JavaScript is not able to send data though. Whenever I place the send method it will not send even though a connection is established. How can I make this work?

Comment: This "question" doesn't appear to be a question any longer, and thus isn't really suited to StackOverflow's format. FWIW, the client's message isn't *encrypted* it's *masked* (obfuscated) by XOR'ing against a random value that is transmitted as a part of the frame. This protocol detail exists to avoid poisoning attacks against proxy servers that might misunderstand the traffic.

Comment: thanks, this answer is very helpful  :)   hey, just one thing, is this "static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";" thing is always constant? if not, where can i get these values?

Comment: i got this: "A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client"

Comment: Why does the WebSocket url ends with '/service' (ws://localhost:8080/service)? Why not just 'ws://localhost:8080'?

Comment: @Charmie I got same message. Have you solve this?

Comment: @andree you can also use it without the "service". Tested by myself.

Comment: Neither works for me with IE nor with FF

Comment: Please do not metamorphose questions into answers - this sort of thing represents a non-trivial stream of created work for volunteer editors. As soon as you have any answer material at all, put it in an answer, and maintain it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

WebSockets is protocol that relies on TCP streamed connection. Although WebSockets is Message based protocol.

If you want to implement your own protocol then I recommend to use latest and stable specification (for 18/04/12) [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).
This specification contains all necessary information regarding handshake and framing. As well most of description on scenarios of behaving from browser side as well as from server side.
It is highly recommended to follow what recommendations tells regarding server side during implementing of your code.

In few words, I would describe working with WebSockets like this:

1. **Create server Socket** (System.Net.Sockets) bind it to specific port, and keep listening with asynchronous accepting of connections. Something like that:

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
serverSocket.Listen(128);
serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
```

2. You should have **accepting** function "OnAccept" that will implement handshake. In future it has to be in another thread if system is meant to handle huge amount of connections per second.

```
private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result) {
    try {
        Socket client = null;
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound) {
            client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
        }
        if (client != null) {
            /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */
        }
    } catch(SocketException exception) {

    } finally {
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound) {
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
}
```

3. After connection established, you have to do **handshake**. Based on specification [1.3 Opening Handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-6), after connection established you will receive basic HTTP request with some information. Example:

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

This example is based on version of protocol 13. Bear in mind that older versions have some differences but mostly latest versions are cross-compatible. Different browsers may send you some additional data. For example Browser and OS details, cache and others.

Based on provided handshake details, you have to generate answer lines, they are mostly same, but will contain Accept-Key, that is based on provided Sec-WebSocket-Key. In specification 1.3 it is described clearly how to generate response key.
Here is my function I've been using for V13:

```
static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
private string AcceptKey(ref string key) {
        string longKey = key + guid;
        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(longKey));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
}
```

Handshake answer looks like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

But accept key have to be the generated one based on provided key from client and method AcceptKey I provided before. As well, make sure after last character of accept key you put two new lines "\r\n\r\n".

4. After handshake answer is sent from server, client should trigger "**onopen**" function, that means you can send messages after.
5. Messages are not sent in raw format, but they have **Data Framing**. And from client to server as well implement masking for data based on provided 4 bytes in message header. Although from server to client you don't need to apply masking over data. Read section [5. Data Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-27) in specification.
   Here is copy-paste from my own implementation. It is not ready-to-use code, and have to be modified, I am posting it just to give an idea and overall logic of read/write with WebSocket framing. Go to [this link](http://moka.me.uk/files/wsreadwrite.txt).
6. After framing is implemented, make sure that you receive data right way using sockets. For example to prevent that some messages get merged into one, because TCP is still stream based protocol. That means you have to read ONLY specific amount of bytes. Length of message is always based on header and provided data length details in header it self. So when you receiving data from Socket, first receive 2 bytes, get details from header based on Framing specification, then if mask provided another 4 bytes, and then length that might be 1, 4 or 8 bytes based on length of data. And after data it self. After you read it, apply demasking and your message data is ready to use.
7. You might want to use some **Data Protocol**, I recommend to use JSON due traffic economy and easy to use on client side in JavaScript. For server side you might want to check some of parsers. There is lots of them, google can be really helpful.

Implementing own WebSockets protocol definitely have some benefits and great experience you get as well as control over protocol it self. But you have to spend some time doing it, and make sure that implementation is highly reliable.

In same time you might have a look in ready to use solutions that google (again) have enough.

Comment: I guess I am stuck on the handshaking. when a new connection is received I have to send to the client the sha1 hash of the long key plus short key right?

Comment: I added more info in section 3. It describes more details over handshake from server side.

Comment: As well make sure that if in request protocols are provided, use same in response for Sec-WebSocket-Protocol line. But only if there is provided in request.
As well you don't need Version for response. And add another NewLine to the end.
As well send whole response string encoded using UTF8: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseBytes)

Comment: We are close. Thanks so much for the help. I am able to send a message now but the message is encrypted I believe. Take a look at my edit that I will start working on soon...

Comment: You have to implement data framing, this will be I believe most complicated bit in implementing of WebSockets protocol.
I will add copy-paste code from my implementation into post, but make sure you edit it, because it have some things to change, but in overall gives an idea and logic of working with frame.

Answer (score 17):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

I am able to send data now. This is my new version of the program thanks to your answers and the code of @Maksims Mihejevs.

### Server

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
            serverSocket.Listen(128);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);            
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                Socket client = null;
                string headerResponse = "";
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                    var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                    headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0,i);
                    // write received data to the console
                    Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);

                }
                if (client != null)
                {
                    /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */

                    var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                              .Split('`')[1]                     // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ== \r\n .......
                              .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                              .Trim();

                    // key should now equal dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                    var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                    var newLine = "\r\n";

                    var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                         + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                         + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                         + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                         ;

                    // which one should I use? none of them fires the onopen method
                    client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));

                    var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message

                    // once the message is received decode it in different formats
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, i));                    

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to send data to client");
                    Console.Read();

                    var subA = SubArray<byte>(buffer, 0, i);
                    client.Send(subA);
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);//wait for message to be send


                }
            }
            catch (SocketException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
                }
            }
        }

        public static T[] SubArray<T>(T[] data, int index, int length)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }

        private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
        {
            string longKey = key + guid;
            byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
        {
            return sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
        }
    }
}
```

### JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function connect() {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/service");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                alert("About to send data");
                ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
                alert("Message sent!");
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                alert("About to receive data");
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message received = "+received_msg);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                // websocket is closed.
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        };


    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:xx-large" >
    <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="connect()">Click here to start</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run that code I am able to send and receive data from both the client and the server. The only problem is that the messages are encrypted when they arrive to the server. Here are the steps of how the program runs:

[image]

Note how the message from the client is encrypted.

Comment: at least i had a problem in chrome complaining about masking, i had to consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932662/websockets-disconnects-on-server-message and than it worked, thanks.

Comment: As it is, this program doesn't seem to work as the connection is always closed before the client properly receives the data.

Answer (score 16):

I couldnt find a simple working example anywhere (as of Jan 19), so here is an updated version. I have chrome version 71.0.3578.98.

**C# Websocket server :**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
    static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
        serverSocket.Listen(1); //just one socket
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            Socket client = null;
            string headerResponse = "";
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
                // write received data to the console
                Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);
                Console.WriteLine("=====================");
            }
            if (client != null)
            {
                /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */
                var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                          .Split('`')[1]                     // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ== \r\n .......
                          .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                          .Trim();

                // key should now equal dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                var newLine = "\r\n";

                var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                     + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                     + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                     + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                     //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                     //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                     ;

                client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
                var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message
                string browserSent = GetDecodedData(buffer, i);
                Console.WriteLine("BrowserSent: " + browserSent);

                Console.WriteLine("=====================");
                //now send message to client
                client.Send(GetFrameFromString("This is message from server to client."));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);//wait for message to be sent
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static T[] SubArray<T>(T[] data, int index, int length)
    {
        T[] result = new T[length];
        Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
        return result;
    }

    private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
    {
        string longKey = key + guid;
        byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    }

    static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
    {
        return sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
    }

    //Needed to decode frame
    public static string GetDecodedData(byte[] buffer, int length)
    {
        byte b = buffer[1];
        int dataLength = 0;
        int totalLength = 0;
        int keyIndex = 0;

        if (b - 128 <= 125)
        {
            dataLength = b - 128;
            keyIndex = 2;
            totalLength = dataLength + 6;
        }

        if (b - 128 == 126)
        {
            dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
            keyIndex = 4;
            totalLength = dataLength + 8;
        }

        if (b - 128 == 127)
        {
            dataLength = (int)BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { buffer[9], buffer[8], buffer[7], buffer[6], buffer[5], buffer[4], buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
            keyIndex = 10;
            totalLength = dataLength + 14;
        }

        if (totalLength > length)
            throw new Exception("The buffer length is small than the data length");

        byte[] key = new byte[] { buffer[keyIndex], buffer[keyIndex + 1], buffer[keyIndex + 2], buffer[keyIndex + 3] };

        int dataIndex = keyIndex + 4;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = dataIndex; i < totalLength; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ key[count % 4]);
            count++;
        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, dataIndex, dataLength);
    }

    //function to create  frames to send to client 
    /// <summary>
    /// Enum for opcode types
    /// </summary>
    public enum EOpcodeType
    {
        /* Denotes a continuation code */
        Fragment = 0,

        /* Denotes a text code */
        Text = 1,

        /* Denotes a binary code */
        Binary = 2,

        /* Denotes a closed connection */
        ClosedConnection = 8,

        /* Denotes a ping*/
        Ping = 9,

        /* Denotes a pong */
        Pong = 10
    }

    /// <summary>Gets an encoded websocket frame to send to a client from a string</summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to encode into the frame</param>
    /// <param name="Opcode">The opcode of the frame</param>
    /// <returns>Byte array in form of a websocket frame</returns>
    public static byte[] GetFrameFromString(string Message, EOpcodeType Opcode = EOpcodeType.Text)
    {
        byte[] response;
        byte[] bytesRaw = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message);
        byte[] frame = new byte[10];

        long indexStartRawData = -1;
        long length = (long)bytesRaw.Length;

        frame[0] = (byte)(128 + (int)Opcode);
        if (length <= 125)
        {
            frame[1] = (byte)length;
            indexStartRawData = 2;
        }
        else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535)
        {
            frame[1] = (byte)126;
            frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[3] = (byte)(length & 255);
            indexStartRawData = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            frame[1] = (byte)127;
            frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 56) & 255);
            frame[3] = (byte)((length >> 48) & 255);
            frame[4] = (byte)((length >> 40) & 255);
            frame[5] = (byte)((length >> 32) & 255);
            frame[6] = (byte)((length >> 24) & 255);
            frame[7] = (byte)((length >> 16) & 255);
            frame[8] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[9] = (byte)(length & 255);

            indexStartRawData = 10;
        }

        response = new byte[indexStartRawData + length];

        long i, reponseIdx = 0;

        //Add the frame bytes to the reponse
        for (i = 0; i < indexStartRawData; i++)
        {
            response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
            reponseIdx++;
        }

        //Add the data bytes to the response
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
            reponseIdx++;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
}
```

**Client html and javascript:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/websession');
        socket.onopen = function() {
           // alert('handshake successfully established. May send data now...');
           socket.send("Hi there from browser.");
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                //alert("About to receive data");
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message received = "+received_msg);
            };
        socket.onclose = function() {
            alert('connection closed');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `long` instead of `int` for the length of the raw data in `GetFrameFromString`. Otherwise your bit shifting for messages larger then `65535` can result in a value that is different then the actual length. Since `int` can go up to `2,147,483,647` and `long` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, which is the frame limit of RFC6455.

Comment: This works using Chrome, but errors when using FF due to negative message length, even with @funie200 's fix.

Comment: I get the following error on Accept Event called first time 

System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range. (Parameter 'asyncResult')
  Source=System.Net.Sockets

Answer (score 6):

WebSockets are [implemented with a protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) that involves [handshake between client and server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3). I don't imagine they work very much like normal sockets. Read up on the protocol, and get your application to talk it. Alternatively, use an existing WebSocket library, or .Net4.5beta which has a [WebSocket API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Of course they work very much like normal sockets.  The socket is at a lower level than the application protocol and, as such, is not dependent on it.  That means you can run FTP, SMTP, HTTP, WebSockets, etc... on a socket.  It's up to the implementer to make sure she follows the protocol correctly or nobody will be able to talk to the server.

Answer (score 3):

### Issue

Since you are using WebSocket, spender is correct. After recieving the initial data from the WebSocket, you need to send the handshake message from the C# server before any further information can flow.

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
WebSocket-Origin: example
WebSocket-Location: something.here
WebSocket-Protocol: 13
```

Something along those lines.

You can do some more research into how WebSocket works on w3 or google.

### Links and Resources

Here is a protocol specifcation: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76#section-1.3

**List of working examples:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866975/184746
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212752/184746
- http://ashishware.com/websocksample.shtml
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?99842-WebSocket-server-in-C

Comment: Also I am using UTF8 encoding. Should I use a different one such as ASCII?

Comment: @TonoNam: As far as i know, UTF8 encoding is correct - although I'm not an HTML5 expert, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I made it work with safari!!! I need it to make it work with google chrome though. All the examples connect but none of them successfully send data. I'll keep trying. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Ofcourse.... If I still dont get it working I will make this question into a bounty one! I am realy curious to see this working. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your protocol spec link is out of date.  Safari still uses this but other browsers have moved on to the incompatible [RFC 6455](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455).  Also, while you're correct that initial connection requires some negotiation, further messages do not.