# HTML5 Websocket connects to Windows .NET server but does not recieve the WebSocket.onopen notification..

Tags: .net, html, client, websocket

Below is the Simple server code

```
// Webserver1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Webserver1.h"
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WEBSERVER1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WEBSERVER1));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WEBSERVER1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WEBSERVER1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//

int ServerThread(LPVOID param)
{
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %ld\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for listening for
    // incoming connection requests.
    SOCKET ListenSocket;
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    service.sin_port = htons(27015);

    if (bind(ListenSocket,
             (SOCKADDR *) & service, sizeof (service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"bind failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Listen for incoming connection requests.
    // on the created socket
    if (listen(ListenSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for accepting incoming requests.
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;
    wprintf(L"Waiting for client to connect...\n");

    //----------------------
    // Accept the connection.
    AcceptSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else
        wprintf(L"Client connected.\n");

    char *sendbuf = "Client: sending data test";
    char recvbuff[1024];
    int dwBytesWrite;
/*

        dwBytesWrite = recv(AcceptSocket,recvbuff , (int)sizeof(recvbuff), 0);
       if (SOCKET_ERROR == dwBytesWrite )
       {
            printf("rev failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;

       }
*/
        dwBytesWrite = send(AcceptSocket,sendbuf , (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
       if (SOCKET_ERROR == dwBytesWrite )
       {
            printf("rev failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;

       }
    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE dispthread;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case ID_FILE_STARTSERVER:
            dispthread=CreateThread(NULL,0,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(ServerThread),NULL,0,&dwThreadId);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Here is the HTML5 client side code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:27015/echo");
     ws.onopen = function(evt)
     {
     alert("Message i11111");
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        ws.send("Message to send");
        alert("Message is sent...");
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert("Message is received...");
     };
     ws.onerror = function (evt) 
     { 
      //  var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert("ERROR...!!");
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:3px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

On debugging i find that the client connection gets accepted by the server, but the client doesnt get the onopen notification, but gets the onclose notification, whats could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocket on client side will throw onopen event only when handshake is proceed by both sides and it was successful.
When WebSocket connects to server, it sends HTTP opening handshake lines with some details in them. It contains important information and server should generate HTTP opening handshake answer based on this data from client.
Especially Key that comes from client, have to be processed and answer key have to be generated.
After handshake is done and it was validated, "onopen" event will trigger on client side, and client is able to send messages after that, same for server. Otherwise after some timeout client will throw onerror and onclose after and browser will force disconnect socket.

Check out official specification [RFC 6455, Section 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-6)

Comment: I am very new to this, can you please elaborate or provide an example on how its done..

Comment: Here is one of my big posts some time ago, it has some code parts of doing handshake and so on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-wold-websocket-example/10206861#10206861
As well you might find some useful stuff here: https://github.com/dude-seriously/gh12-server under Protocol and Sockets folders.