# Websockets - disconnects on server message

Tags: c#, websocket, handshake

I'm new to Websockets and looking for working samples using WS and c# console application.
I ran into [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-wold-websocket-example), but i already have a problem. It seems that connection is closed when server sends a message to client. I'm not sure but i think handshake is ok. Here is a code:

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
            serverSocket.Listen(128);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                Socket client = null;
                string headerResponse = "";
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                    var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                    headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
                    // write received data to the console
                    Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);
                    Console.WriteLine("=====================");
                }
                if (client != null)
                {
                    /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */

                    var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                              .Split('`')[1]                     // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ== \r\n .......
                              .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                              .Trim();

                    // key should now equal dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                    var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                    var newLine = "\r\n";

                    var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                         + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                         + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                         + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                         ;

                    // which one should I use? none of them fires the onopen method
                    client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));

                    var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message

                    // once the message is received decode it in different formats
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, i));
                    Console.WriteLine("=====================");

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to send data to client");
                    Console.Read();

                    var subA = SubArray<byte>(buffer, 0, i);
                    client.Send(subA);

                    Console.Read();                    
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);//wait for message to be send


                }
            }
            catch (SocketException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
                }
            }
        }

        public static T[] SubArray<T>(T[] data, int index, int length)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }

        private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
        {
            string longKey = key + guid;
            byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
        {
            return sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Clent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function connect() {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/service");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                alert("About to send data");
                ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
                alert("Message sent!");
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                alert("About to receive data");
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message received = "+received_msg);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                // websocket is closed.
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        };


    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:xx-large" >
    <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="connect()">Click here to start</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a connection request and message from client:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just "echo" the buffer you received. The RFC says, that frames from client to server must be masked. It doesn't say that messages from server to client must not, but at least for Chrome it shouldn't.
Hence, if you want to echo data, you have to decode (unmask) the frame and construct a new one. The payload needs to be XOR'ed byte-by-byte with the mask key.

Or simply send data like this:

```
byte[] send = new byte[3 + 2];
send[0] = 0x81; // last frame, text
send[1] = 3; // not masked, length 3
send[2] = 0x41;
send[3] = 0x42;
send[4] = 0x43;
nwStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length); // nwStream = client.GetStream(), client is a TcpClient
```

Comment: Fantastic Jeff, Bravo. Hats off to you "the king of all websockets". Thank you very much for the amazing answer.

Answer (score 3):

JeffRSon is correct. But it should be noted that section 5.1 of RFC 6455 does mention;

... A server MUST NOT mask any frames that it sends to the client. A client MUST close a connection if it detects a masked frame. ...

Comment: were you able to fix it?