# Client/Server Chat Application through Internet

Tags: c#, php, sockets, tcp

I tried the following example , it works perfectly in my LAN.

[Chat Application Using Asynchronous TCP Sockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16916/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-TCP-Sockets)

Now, is there any possibility to do it online through the Internet?

NOTE: I have a free Webhosting Server (PHP). Or a WindowsServer with Internet Connection.

I've done some researches in google, but didn't found something helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcp works just fine over the internet - however, it requires:

- that the clients have access to each-other over TCP and some public IP address
- that the ports required are open at all firewalls (in particular, inbound is likely to be blocked)

Neither of which is *generally* going to be the case. For internet purposes, in the context of "chat", you would typically have a central server acting as a hub, making it easy to satisfy both bullets.

If by "internet" you actually mean "web server", you might want to look into web-sockets (a duplex messaging protocol layered on top of TCP, negotiated initially via HTTP (before protocol-switching), and with good support in most browsers).

Comment: Thank you sir, I have searched for Web-Sockets, I found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-wold-websocket-example) this one. Do you think, it will work for me?

Comment: @StackUnderflow to implement web-sockets correctly requires a *lot* more code than that (source: I wrote the web-socket server that we use here at stackoverflow); I would strongly recommend using a pre-existing library. Or for a framework that has fallback strategies, things like SignalR

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, as long as you can provide a listening port on a non-private IP.

If you want to do this with PHP, you might want to think about a Server that is polled by the clients and backed by a database, as long running PHP processes tend to create more problems than they solve.

If your Windows server has an external IP or you have enough control over the routing/firewall/NAT you should be able to use the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For use it thought Internet, you have to configure your router for redirect the server port to your computer.