# Send data to server use Websocket server in C#

Tags: c#, websocket, server, send

I want to send "Hello word" to server. I perform like [Create "Hello World" WebSocket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-world-websocket-example)

1. I click start of visual.
2. I run HTML. click link (Click here to start)
3. Run localhost:8080/service
4. enter in box
   [image]

and show error:
[image]

It don't show like last picture [image]
Help me, please! 
Thank you!

Comment: The example you linked doesn't mask its data unlike the code you're attempting to run. Google "a server must not mask" and you will certainly find hints of what you can do to solve it. Also, try another browser like Firefox or IE and make sure they are up to date. Keep in mind though that masking is forbidden by the protocol specification itself which is why Chrome is attempting to detect it in the first place.

Comment: Yep :)) I tried to use Firefox, It worked. But Chrome not work :((

Comment: #bokibeg, #MikDiet. Thank you very much!