# Javascript working in Google Chrome but Blocked in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, websocket

Using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-world-websocket-example#) for testing. The javascript runs just fine in Google Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

Ok so it works in IE if I run the html file locally but it does give me a warning at the bottom of the page saying it has disabled some scripts on the page and I have to click it to enable them.(doesnt happen in chrome) but ok I do that and it works. But I then put it on my remote webserver which just hosts the HTML file. The connection is still going to be local to the browser viewing the site. However this wont work in IE but could be because it doesn't even show a warning about the script. The page loads but the js doesn't run.

Im assuming that IE is blocking it by default.

How can I get round this and make it work like it does in chrome. The html/js is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function connect() {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/service");
        ws.onopen = function () {
            alert("About to send data");
            ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
            alert("Message sent!");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            alert("About to receive data");
            var received_msg = evt.data;
            alert("Message received = "+received_msg);
        };
        ws.onclose = function () {
            // websocket is closed.
            alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
    };


</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:xx-large" >
<div>
<a href="#" onclick="connect()">Click here to start connection</a></div>
<a href="webSocketTest:">First Open program</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to [adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902179/adam-pilacki) i have checked the f12 Developer console and I get an error:
`SCRIPT5022: SecurityError`

Comment: `The page loads but the js doesn't. ` - I'm sure it loads, it probably just doesn't run

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Tested on IE11 and also on Edge. Edge never gives a popup but im assuming its the same problem.

Comment: Could you try change your doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>. As the WebSocket is part of the HTML5 initative, i could imagine that maybe IE blocks it because you file is not a valid HTML5 document. Sadly i cant test it myself at the moment.

Comment: I have tried, but not succeeded. The f12 Developer console give a HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>". Ill update the post to what I have changed it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the people that have helped.

The Problem is to do with IE and Edge browser not wanting to connect to "Localhost" however if you change Localhost to 127.0.0.1 it works perfectly.

**Updated Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function connect() {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/service");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                alert("About to send data");
                ws.send("Hello World"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO THE SERVER!!!!!!!!
                alert("Message sent!");
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                alert("About to receive data");
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message received = "+received_msg);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                // websocket is closed.
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        };


    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:xx-large" >
    <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="connect()">Click here to start connection</a></div>
<a href="webSocketTest:">First Open program</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`ws://localhost:8080/service`

to

`ws://{your_remote_domain_host}:8080/service`

and it should work

Comment: why would it be on the domin? I am wanting it to connect over localhost to a sever running on the local machine not the webserver

Comment: You wrote: 'put it on my remote webserver' - so remote or local? :D

Comment: The html file is hosted on a webserver but the connection it is making is still  local to the computer viewing the website. It works perfectly in Chrome :/ I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I see - so websocket server is on your local machine... so is there some error message in console - I mean IE js console as well as server console?

Comment: Never thought to look at the developer console in IE. yea it has an error SCRIPT5022: SecurityError. Ill update the post thanks