# C# Creating websocket - onmessage function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I'have created websocket like this:

[Create "Hello World" WebSocket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-world-websocket-example)

I have a problem because server doesn't send message to Client and in JS script function onmessage() is never fired. The connection is closed right after second send() on server is fired or after while. Do you know how to fix it? There is no respectable documentation for websockets and I couldn't find right answer why it doesn't work. Thanks for all answers.

@edit
There is an error after sending second message.
An error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host.

There is also an error in javascript. When the second message is sending I get an error: Invalid frame header.

I have no idea why the first message with header works but the second with data doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. When u use socket server and websocket client you have to create your own frame for sending data back to client and it works fine.