# Update Web Application UI from a IP callback in a different thread (ASP.NET and C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, user-interface

I am programming a Web Application with ASP.NET and C#.

When the page loads, it has to listen (IP connection) and when it gets a message,  a label should be updated with that value (update the UI from the callback).
Simplifying my code, I have this for the mainpage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread listeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListening));
        listeningThread.Start();
    }
```

This is the label in the aspx file:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
```

Then, this is my function for the callback:

```
private void StartListening()
    {
        Action<string> callbackRead = (string message) =>
        {
            myLabel.text = message;
        };
    }
```

**The message arrives properly** and if I put a breakpoint inside the callback I can see how it goes inside it. Despite of this, **UI is not updated**. Of course, if I write myLabel.text = "Whatever"; in the Page_Load part, it works fine.

I have tried with a grid and DataSource + DataBind() (I followed [this](https://chsakell.com/2013/07/20/background-processes-in-asp-net-web-forms/) tutorial) but I still have the same problem, it works fine if I do it in the Page_Load but not from the callback.

I have read a lot about this in another questions but non of the answers solves my problem (most are for WinForms, etc.)

I'm new in this field and I know I'm probably missing something. Could you help me, please? How is the right way to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proper way to achieve this is [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: I use SignalR for other parts of the project but didn't think about this one, I'll try.

Comment: I've been trying using this: var context = GlobalHost.Connectio‌​nManager.GetHubContex‌​t<WebApplicationHub>(‌​); context.Clients.All.‌​broadcastMessage("nam‌​e", "message"); but it does nothing. It only works if I use it outside from the callback, like for example, when I press a button.

Answer (score 2):

By setting *myLabel.text = message* you update label text on the **server** side while you [also] need to update text in client browser(s).

Typical approaches here are: [ajax pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example) (you send ajax requests each X seconds to server to check for updates) or [websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/create-hello-world-websocket-example) (your server can push updates directly to client browsers).

Comment: But when I set the text = "message" directly in the Page_Load, it works for the UI too without any ajax pulling or websockets help.

Comment: Correct, because Page_Load happens before actual HTML is rendered while your background worker can update it after.