# WebSocket windows service listening on port 8080

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, windows-services

I'm new to Windows service development, and need to build one in C# that will listen on port `8080` for data coming in, then parse it. I've found information about `System.Net.WebSockets`, `System.Net.Sockets`, and third-party libraries, such as `SuperSocket`. 
There's this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206861/177416), but not sure what goes in the `OnStart()` and what goes in `OnStop()` methods of my Windows service class. Another example is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server), but that's also not covering Windows service specifically. For basic Windows service development, there's this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I'm thinking this goes in `OnStart()`:

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
serverSocket.Listen(128);
serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
```

What would I put into the `OnStop()`?

The data stream coming in doesn't require any authentication. Would I still need to do a handshake?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wish to use port 8080 as listening port, I'm going to assume you are essentially dealing with http traffic. Instead of using raw sockets, you should look into [OWIN Self Hosted](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) web server. Alternatively [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) can work as well.

`OnStop()` is called when windows tries to stop the service. You can think of it as your Dispose for service. `OnStart()` is similarly your function to do initializations. I'd suggest you look into the really nice library [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to start writing Windows Services.