# Unable to subscribe to a specific channel on WebSocket using c#

Tags: c#, websocket

I have websocket listner in this way in JavaScript.

```
var connectionLostMessage = null;

    function websocketConnect() {
        var conn = new ab.Session('ws://abc.xyz.dd:8080?time=1627624930.3964',
            function () {
                clearTimeout(connectionLostMessage);
                connectionLostMessage = null;

                conn.subscribe('316627', function (topic, data) {
                    //some code to use data display
                });
            },
            function () {
                //When connection fails
                //Connection fail handling

                setTimeout(function () {
                    websocketConnect();
                }, 1000)
            },
            {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
        );
    }

    websocketConnect();
```

I want to connect and subscribe to the channel using c# as found in JavaScript in following line.

```
conn.subscribe('316627', function (topic, data) {
```

I have tried with in this way but unable to subscribe in the way above.

```
public async Task WebsocketClientTest()
{
    var url = new Uri("ws://abc.xyz.dd:8080");
    var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    using (var client = new WebsocketClient(url))
    {
        client.MessageReceived
            .Subscribe(msg => Console.WriteLine($"msg.Text: {msg.Text},  msg.MessageType: {msg.MessageType}"));
        
        await client.Start();
        exitEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I need to write a console application in .Net Core. Please suggest any help or third party compatible with .Net Core 3.1

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to send a message before receiving.  So the message received you be after the WaitOne.

Comment: Hi jdweng, I tried the way as suggested but not works. So, I have updated my question to explain more in detail the situation I have. Please see the updated question and suggest how I should proceed. thanks!

Comment: Where are you writing to the client?

Comment: I am writing the client in c# console application. The aim is to capture the data as per channel ID as shown in Javascript example above.

Comment: You are missing parameters new ab.Session('ws://abc.xyz.dd:8080?time=1627624930.3964' and headers conn.subscribe('316627', function (topic, data)

Comment: Yes, but how this can be done in c#?

Comment: The parameters are part of the URI.   Headers like UPGRADE are shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/creating-a-hello-world-websocket-example

Comment: The shared other thread also describing the solution for client in Javascript. In my case, I have working example of client in Javascript. I want to write similar client using c# in console application.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng your first answer is actually the solution. I was sending the message in client in wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution this way as proposed by **jdweng** in above comments. The only thing I was doing wrong the format of the message to send. My question is also missing the send line after question editing.

```
client.Send($"[5, \"123456"]");
```